# Can i turn my eclipse project into linux application?

Tags: java

Right now I'm working on a app, using eclipse on windows 10. I want to know can i turn my project into a linux runable file?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please have a look to [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is far too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm):

> To create a new runnable JAR file in the workbench:
>
> 1. From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
> 2. Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
> 3. In the Opens the Runnable JAR export wizard Runnable JAR File Specification page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR.
> 4. In the Export destination field, either type or click Browse to select a location for the JAR file.
> 5. Select an appropriate library handling strategy.
> 6. Optionally, you can also create an ANT script to quickly regenerate a previously created runnable JAR file.

This will create a new runnable jar file, which can be executed on all operating systems that have a JRE installed.